# Outlook: I have accidentally duplicated a series meeting. How do I find out which was the original one?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I have accidentally duplicated a series meeting invitation.

This happened by accidentally pressing Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V. I thought I'd copy and paste things in a different window.

Now there are duplicate invitation series at the exact same time, same participiants, content and location. I assume that if I edit the copy of the series or single events from that in the future it will produce a mess. I think participients will then also get double invitations step by step. 
I want to prevent that by deleting the copy.

But how can I discern the original from the copy? I fail to see any difference between both invitation series.

Comment: Next time this happens, press CTRL-Z to undo. This works at most places when Microsoft is the one who made the software, including Office, Explorer, etc. It will delete whatever was added.

Comment: @LPChip Good idea. But what if I realise it hours later?

Comment: Did you already send the invite out? You could check the Tracking history to see who accepted/declined etc...

Comment: @spikey_richie: Did not send it out. That's it. The copy has no status button at all. That is an obvious difference, I can use for discerning the copy from the original. I will accept that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up the two recurring events, you can compare the Tracking status. It's likely the invite with the accept/decline responses is the one you want to keep.

[image]

[image]